# Kotlin REST to typescript definitions

Tags: rest, maven, typescript, jax-rs, kotlin

Hello there everybody,

I've got a project written in Kotlin with REST api in JAX-RS.

I wanna use maven task to generate relevant typescript API with DTOs defined.

I found projekt https://github.com/raphaeljolivet/java2typescript, which seems to be perfect for this purpose, actually it does not satisfy all needed.

Do you know some other generators for generating REST and DTOs according to REST API?

Thanks a lot for your help and discussion

Answer (score 0):

You can use swagger for this purpose.

Step 1: Write your API in swagger.yaml: http://editor.swagger.io/

Step 2: Generate sample swagger project for generating java from API definition: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar meta -o output/myLibrary -n myClientCodegen -p com.my.company.codegen
```

Step 3: Adjust generated project for generating kotlin classes.

Repeat these steps for TypeScript (consumer part).